# Get previously deployed proxy contract in a seperate deployment file using hardhat-upgrades

Tags: node.js, ethers.js, hardhat, openzeppelin

I have deployed a token like so using hardhat

```
const { getNamedAccounts, deployments, network } = hre
const { deploy, log, get } = deployments
const { deployer } = await getNamedAccounts()
log("----------------------------------------------------")
log("Deploying GovernanceToken and waiting for confirmations...")

const governanceTokenContractFactory = await ethers.getContractFactory(GOVERNANCE_TOKEN_NAME);
console.log(`Deploying ${GOVERNANCE_TOKEN_NAME}...`);

const deployedProxy = await upgrades.deployProxy(governanceTokenContractFactory, [], {
  initializer: "initialize",
  kind: "uups",
});


await deployedProxy.deployed();
console.log(`${GOVERNANCE_TOKEN_NAME} proxy deployed to: ${deployedProxy.address}`);

const governanceToken = await governanceTokenContractFactory.attach(
    deployedProxy.address
);
```

In a seperate script I'm trying to deploy the governor which requires the governance token.  Normally I would be able to get the deployed token like so:

```
const governanceToken = await get(GOVERNANCE_TOKEN_NAME)
//const governanceToken = await ethers.getContract(GOVERNANCE_TOKEN_NAME)
```

I'm getting an error when I try to do so:

> Error: No Contract deployed with name GovernanceToken

My guess is that this is related to me using `@openzeppelin/hardhat-upgrades` to deploy and that its not registering it the same way it would during normal deployment:

```
import { upgrades } from "hardhat"
```

How can I get a previously deployed proxy contract in a seperate deployment file using hardhat-upgrades?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after deploying I needed to save the artifact.

```
const { getNamedAccounts, deployments, network } = hre
const { deploy, log, get } = deployments
const { deployer } = await getNamedAccounts()
log("----------------------------------------------------")
log("Deploying GovernanceToken and waiting for confirmations...")

const governanceTokenContractFactory = await ethers.getContractFactory(GOVERNANCE_TOKEN_NAME);
console.log(`Deploying ${GOVERNANCE_TOKEN_NAME}...`);

const deployedProxy = await upgrades.deployProxy(governanceTokenContractFactory, [], {
  initializer: "initialize",
  kind: "uups",
});


await deployedProxy.deployed();
console.log(`${GOVERNANCE_TOKEN_NAME} proxy deployed to: ${deployedProxy.address}`);

const governanceToken = await governanceTokenContractFactory.attach(
    deployedProxy.address
);
const artifact = await deployments.getExtendedArtifact(GOVERNANCE_TOKEN_NAME);
const proxyDeployments = {
    address: deployedProxy.address,
    ...artifact
}

await save(GOVERNANCE_TOKEN_NAME, proxyDeployments);
```